# How to properly concatenate string and tag result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I am making a rails helper for creating of a login button with a text and a logo image.
If I put as content only a text or image_tag result it works very well.

```
def test_helper
  anchor = content_tag :a, "enter by", :href => '#'
  concat content_tag :div, anchor, :class => 'login'
end

# result:
# <div class="login"><a href="#">enter by</a></div>

def test_helper
  anchor = content_tag :a, image_tag("logo.png"), :href => '#'
  concat content_tag :div, anchor, :class => 'login'
end

# result:
# <div class="login"><a href="#"><img src="assets/logo.png" /></a></div>
```

But when I try to pass result of concatenation it is returned an img tag with escape symbols in html source:

```
def test_helper
  anchor = content_tag :a, "enter by" + image_tag("logo.png"), :href => '#'
  concat content_tag :div, anchor, :class => 'login'
end

<div class="login"><a href="#">enter by&lt;img src=&quot;/assets/logo.png&quot; /&gt;</a></div>
```

How to properly concatenate a string and a result of content_tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because of the concatenation being done when building the anchor_tag.  You need to call `html_safe` on the string literal to avoid the escaping:

```
anchor = content_tag :a, "enter by".html_safe + image_tag("logo.png"), :href => '#'
```

Comment: Ohh, sorry.. I lose bracket when had made copy-paste.

Comment: With anchor.html_safe I get same result ((

Comment: You're right, that's not the problem - updated with a new solution.

Comment: It returns <div>{:class=&gt;&quot;login&quot;}</div>

Comment: Ok, one more try :)  And use parenthesis in case ruby is getting confused on the parsing...

Comment: It works, but still returns with escaping <div class="login"><a href="#">enter by&lt;img alt=&quot;Logo&quot; src=&quot;/assets/logo.png&quot; /&gt;</a></div>

Comment: First answer is near to be correct except html_safe must be applied as  ("enter by " + image_tag).html_safe not anchor.html_safe. Please correct answer and I'll mark answer as accepted.

Comment: Actually, only the "enter by" string needs to be marked as `html_safe`, which I discovered as testing it myself. Updated.